# Multiple $_REQUEST within a URL

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so I've made a page named **users.php** which checks if a user id is requested.
It's like www.domain.com/users.php?user_id=1;

Now, what I want to do is..to have another clause in the URL.
Something like this :- **www.domain.com/users.php?user_id=1&action=display**

How should I proceed so that "action" clause can be used as well ?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check for the action in the $_GET variable.

```
if(isset($_GET['action')){
     // do what you want when action is set
     $action = $_GET['action'];
}else{
     // do something else when action is not set
}
```

Comment: Ok, so do you mean that I should have a URL something like this :- **<form action="www.domain.com/users.php?user_id=1&action=displayservices" method="post">**

Comment: Actually, the approach @shankar-damodaran gave for the html form should be used. Cause using the action embedded in the action attribute of the form tag is not good pratice. What if you want to change the action, so you want for example, delete a user? You should change the action attribute, and that would be a pain in the ass. Using a hidden input is a better practice, and better to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

In your **`<form>`** introduce another field

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="display">
```

and in your PHP file you can access it as

```
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
```

Comment: Note that the form method should be GET.

Comment: Yeah right. Made it as a `$_REQUEST` for a safer side.